# formatting currencies with Python

Tags: python, string, integer, format, currency

I would like to format integers as professional looking currency strings. For example:

1200000 -> $1.2 million
456 -> $456.00

Do you know a good library for this, ideally with localization to handle European formats.

Comment: oh dear: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such formatting seems reasonable in some limited uses.  But, should 1200000 be formatted as 1.2 million or 1.20 million?  And isn't 456 more friendly as $456 (without the cents)?

Adding cents to large precise numbers is common in sweepstakes mailers (*Ed McMann says you can win $12,000,000.00*).

It seems a careful specification of what the proper output for different kinds of numbers is the larger problem.  Once that's done, it would be pretty straightforward to write a formatting function.

Answer (score 4):

[`locale.currency()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.currency) can handle the number bits, but I've not seen a module for the word part.